# Change connect.offsets kafka connector error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I sync data from binlog mysql to kafka, and sometime binlog file has been removed, and i get an error when restart connector

`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: The connector is trying to read binlog starting at binlog file 'mysql-bin.000003', pos=154, skipping 0 events plus 0 rows`

I change /tmp/connect.offsets to current binlog file. But it loads all data from database push topic again. I want to prevent this, I only want to load changes from binlog file.

Comment: Which connector are you using? Are you using Kafka Connect standalone for a good reason? Generally Distributed (even on a single node) is recommended

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I'm using Kafka Connect standalone with Debezium plugin

Answer (score 1):

this is expected behaviour. The Debezium should never be down that long that any binlog that has not beens seen was removed as this would lead to data inconsistency so the error message is correct.

The right remedy to this situation is using `snapshot.mode=when_needed`. The other solution you've correctl mentioned is offset manipulation. But here you must have mady any mistake as what you describes sounds like the connecotr was unable to find offsets at all so it think it statrs from scratch and initiates a new snapshot.

Comment: Jiri Pechanec, I try your way, but it still load all row database to topic, I only want to load the changes in binlog file

Comment: With the offset manipulation it should only resume streaming. But bear in mind you will lose data that were no longer available in binlog.